# How to have a "home" page when all is routed through index.php

Tags: php, restler

I'm struggling with how to integrate Restler with a website. If we take the simplest example: hello world it requires that `.htaccess` route everything through index.php. But what if my home page needs to reside there? So for example, how can I simply:

1. Have a "home" page the user lands on when they enter my site
2. To proceed on, perhaps a form is on the this page that they can submit to my class in restler

There is a forms example in the docs but its incredibly complex and requires using other frameworks. I want to start simple. Currently, if I follow the hello world example but choose to enter my site home mysite.org/index.php I get the error

```
"{
    "error": {
      "code": 404,
      "message": "Not Found"
    },
    "debug": {
      "source": "Routes.php:436 at route stage",
      "stages": {
         "success": [ "get" ],
         "failure": [ "route", "negotiate", "message" ]
      }
    }
}".
```

How do I make index.php something the visitor can work with?

Answer (score 0):

create a class to be mapped to the root of the website. Say for example Home class

```
class Home {
   public function index(){
       return "The content for root";
   }
}
```

And then when adding the Home class map it to root

```
$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Home',''); //second parameter is the path to map it to where blank means root
...
```

Now your api root will respond with `"The content for root"`

Answer (score 0):

I've always installed the restler related stuff into a subdirectory of my website called API, and that's where the .htaccess does the rewrites.  That way my website is still a "normal" website, and then all the API stuff lives in its own directory.